# SSRS Report Manager language suddenly switching

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2014

We've been experiencing lately some issues with SSRS report manager language, which switches suddenly from French to English (happened 2 times), and vice versa.

Note that the clients browsers are in French and report manager is still showing in English which is strange.

Note also that :

- Host server (where Sql Server is installed) OS language is French
- This issue happened some days after upgrading from SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2014
- In the source code of the rendered HTML pages of Report Manager we see that the language declaration in the HEAD tag is in French though : `<HEAD lang="fr-FR">`

Anybody knows how could this happen? or how to set the default language of Report Manager independently of the clients browsers languages?

Thanks.

Regards.

Comment: _something_ must be triggering it. Your mission, should you choose to accept, is to find that something.

Comment: Of course, I just need some tracks to find that something

Comment: According to this, language is a client side setting: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/56a9ca7a-765d-4e47-b1a0-69d3fc05c3b0/how-to-change-user-language-of-reporting-services?forum=sqlreportingservices. It doesn't explain why it switches though

Comment: Do you know if this is part of SSRS configuration? can we say to SSRS to follow or not the client side language?

Comment: Apparently it is according to this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156493.aspx